# Verify the function has a partial derivative

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Verify that the function  $$f(z) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2},  & z=x+iy \neq0; \\
0, & z=0,
\end{cases}
$$

has a partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ equal to $0$ at the origin, and hence it satisfies the *Cauchy-Riemann equation* there; show, however, that it is not even continuous there.

I am struggling with the piecewise function. I can obviously see that the partial derivative for $x$ and $y$ are going to be equal but how do I know they will be equal to $0$?

Comment: Use the definition of derivative as limit of increments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f_x(0,0) = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{0*h}{h} = 0$.  Similarly for $f_y(0,0) = 0$.

Note however that $f_x$ and $f_y$ are NOT continuous at $(0,0)$ because $f$ itself is discontinuous there.  Although $f(0,0)$ is defined the limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ does not exist.